# generate multiple returns under spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using ALS library from Spark, and have some problems of generating multiple returns from one row. say I have a file, and the separator for one line is '#'. So here is what I got so far:

```
val ratings : RDD[Rating] = data.map(_.split('#')).map(items => {
   for (i <- 1 until items.length) 
      if ( items(i).length() > 2)
         Rating(items(0).toInt, i.toInt, items(i).toDouble)    
})
```

so ideally, i would like to generate the data with Rating type, but the error shows "type mismatched: found Unit, required: org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating"

Is there a way to create multiple rows from one row in Spark using Scala? Any thoughts?

I am using spark 2.1.X and scala 2.11.

Comment: can you add input sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to parse one record from an RDD and based on some condition you will get two records and pass that as result of your map operation.

If that is the case then you can do something like below:

```
val ratings : RDD[Rating] = data.map(_.split('#')).map(items => {

    val list = new ArrayBuffer[Rating]
    for (i <- 1 until items.length) 
        list += Rating(items(i), i.toInt) 

    list
}).flatMap(row => row)
```

Here the `flatMap` will flatten the list of objects into individual records

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass something (Rating(-1, -1, -1.0)), in case `if ( items(i).length() > 2)` this condition not satisfy. and then filter the value based on Rating(-1, -1, -1.0)

example

```
val ratings : RDD[Rating] = data.map(_.split('#')).map(items => 
{
   for (i <- 1 until items.length) 
       if ( items(i).length() > 2)
          Rating(items(0).toInt, i.toInt, items(i).toDouble) 
       else
          Rating(-1, -1, -1.0) 

}
)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. but the error keeps the same after adding the "else" condition.